# Длина рамки CSS

Tags: css

Есть рамка вокруг текста

```
border-top: 1px solid #000; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
padding: 5px;
```

Как сделать рамку длиннее или наоборот?

[image]

Comment: Рамка не может быть длиннее или короче. Вообще нельзя влиять на рамку ее свойствами. Она зависит от размеров элемента, вокруг которого она строится. И, как вам уже подсказали, это можно сделать изменением размеров элемента или его внутренними отступами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
width: 200px;
```

? :)

Answer (score 6):

Не совсем понятно, что именно вам нужно.

- `border-top: 1px solid #000;` - верхняя часть рамки толщиной в `1px` цвета `#000`
- `border-bottom: 1px solid #000;` - нижняя часть рамки `1px` цвета `#000`
- `padding: 5px;` - внутренний отступ (отступ от текста внутри рамки до самой рамки) `5px`

Длина же задается параметром `width` (высота - `height`). Например:

```
width 100px;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
padding: 5px;
```

Возможно, вам поможет [эта статья](http://www.artvictory.com.ua/?ar=35) или [эта](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2012/02/css-ramka.html).

Comment: долго же я писал :)

Answer (score 3):

С помощью `border` такого не сделаешь, она либо на всю длину либо никак. Поробуйте сделать так:

```
div{position:relative;}
div:before{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:50%;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    content:"";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 0 60px 0 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span.long {
  padding: 0 2em;
}

span.long-2 {
  padding: 0 2em;
  margin: 0 -2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Как сделать <span>рамку</span> длиннее?</p>
<p>Как сделать <span class="long">рамку</span> длиннее?</p>
<p>Как сделать только <span class="long-2">рамку</span> длиннее?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Интересно а 10 лет назад были псевдо элементы ::before; ::after?
Можно было было бы так:

```
.parent-element {
    display: flex;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 500px;
    &::after {
        content: '';
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 1px;
        border: 0.5px solid black;
    }
}
```